# What is the best way to reset a component's reactive data in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Let's say there is a component with multiple reactive data. How can we reset them back to the initial state?

```
<script setup>
    const var_a = ref("");
    const var_b = ref([]);
    const var_c = ref({});
    const var_d = ref(false);
    const var_e = ref(1);
    const var_f = ref("a");
    ...
</script>
```

In vue 2 we could do that by just using Object.assign() with an object and simply re/define it to data() whenever needed.

```
<script>
function initialData (){
  return {
    var_a: "",
    var_b: [],
    var_c: {},
    var_d: false,
    var_e: 1,
    var_f: "a",
  }
}

export default {
    data: function (){
        return initialState();
    },
    methods:{
        resetData: function (){
            Object.assign(this.$data, initialData());
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But in vue 3 it does not work that way.

I could declare all the component data on to `const state` then loop trough it but it does not feel like a convenient way.

So what would be the best way to reset those on vue 3?

Comment: as a side comment, not an aswer to your question, for complex data types, it's worth using `reactive` rather than `ref` : `const state = reactive( { var_b: [], var_c: {},  })`

Comment: Yep you are right about that @thiebo, I could use reactive here. Just a habit, I always use ref and rarely reactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the whole state needs to be reset, it shouldn't be defined separately. Instead, it's defined as reactive object:

```
const state = reactive(initialState());
```

It can be reset the same way as before:

```
Object.assign(state, initialState());
```

The state can be used separately if needed:

```
const { var_a } = toRefs(state);
```

Comment: But in that case `state` is necessary, right? I mean the properties can't declared on their own (root) on the context, they have to be in `state`.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's made usable. Not specific to Vue, if you need to process a considerable list of variables together, they need to be defined together as an object.

Comment: Btw, it could be the opposite way, `const var_a = ref(""); ... const state = reactive({ var_a, ... })`. So technically they can be declared on its own. But state is still needed, and this would require to define initial state twice.